# Phonegap IOS - scrollbar appear while I try to scroll home page even if html file was empty

Tags: ios, cordova

I just create a IOS Phonegap app using Terminal, then change
UIWebViewBounce t= false in config.xml, and delete all contents inside
body, and delete all CSS data.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my HTML page, my index.css is empty and my Phonegap version is 2.4. Then I run the app:
[image: App run]

When I try to scroll the empty page, a scroll bar appears:
[image: App run with scrollbar]

Why? Can anyone please help me?

**UPDATE   Solved : just remove height=device-height from meta tag OR Remove status bar **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, This is due to the device status bar, me also faced this issue, it will take almost 20px of window height. Better make sure that you have checked "Hide status bar" option in xcode  Targets.

[image]

Comment: Hiding status will fix it but I think it'll affect user experience. Removing meta viewport height=device-height is better solution. I just don't know why this is included in PhoneGap template by default.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I had to manually disable the iOS's WebView's ScrollView's ScrollIndicator, in the XCode project.

```
self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Comment: did you checked this: just remove height=device-height from meta tag OR Remove status bar